# Can't Run New Main File Xcode

Tags: c, build, xcode4

I have just started learning C programming and using Xcode 4.6.2. When I create a new target for my Xcode project, everything works but Xcode only runs the original target's main class. How can I run my new target's main class?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second, separate source code file that contains your "`main`" function, you can set it's "target membership" by using the "file inspector" (which appears along the right side of the Xcode window).

It looks like this:

[image: You can set target membership this way]

The idea here is that you'll have one "`main`" function in one file for your first target, and a separate "`main`" function in another file for your second target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have two targets and a main function for each one. The problem is that when I try to run the main function for my new target that I created, the compiler runs the one for the original target. How can I choose which main function I want to run?

Comment: See where I did the red circles?  Set the correct checkbox for the .m file that contains the "`main`" function you want to use.